# UICollectionView show images stored in documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsdocumentdirectory

Hello I can get a `UITableView` to display the file name of images stored in the documents folder. Is there any way to get a `UICollectionView` to display these images in a collection view?

Thanks Liam

Comment: Yes, there are lots of tutorials present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Here is a [UICollectionView Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

1. Create array of file names
2. Connect data source to `UICollectionView`
3. In `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return cell with image using `+imageNamed:` method.

Remember to create custom cell with `UIImageView` inside, create outlet.

Here is [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) which should help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // fetch all the files from the documents directory.
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    library = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    fileArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:library error:nil];

    NSArray *imagelist = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    // filter the images from all the files.
    for(int i = 0;i<fileArray.count;i++)
   {
      id object = [fileArray  objectAtIndex:i];
      if ([object rangeOfString:@".png"].location !=NSNotFound)
     {
       [imagelist addObject:object];

     }
  }
```

then create an instance of collection view and use following UICollectionView datasource to add the item in the collection view,

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;